# matching sorted arrays in loop php

Tags: php, mysql

here's a piece of code i tried can anyone please tell me what is that im doing wrong as i'm not getting desired result
 (please see the query gets me the following result's

```
 - 61|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|70|0|0|66|0|0|
 - 63|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|78|0|0|69|0|0|
```

). I want the value `61|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|70|0|0|66|0|0|` to match with `61|66|70|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|` how do i do that??

`$value = '61|66|70|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|'
$toCompare = explode("|", $value, -1);
sort($toCompare );

$query = $db -> query("select groups,category_group from products ");
while($compare = $query -> fetch_assoc()){
    $compareWith = explode("|", $compare['category_group']);
sort($compareWith);
if ($compareWith == $toCompare)
    $compareResult = $compare['category_group'];

}`

Comment: Your $value should be quoted as it is a string.

Comment: have you tried `var_dump($compareWith, $toCompare)` to see whether they are indeed in the same ordeR?

Comment: You have "groups" in your query, but "category_group" in your expression...?

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch only `groups` column from products table but in loop you using `category_group` and  everytime you overwrite on `$compareResult`. Make it array and you will get all result array.

```
 $compareResult = array();
 $query = $db -> query("select groups,category_group from products ");
  while($compare = $query -> fetch_assoc()){
       $compareWith = explode("|", $compare['category_group']);
       sort($compareWith);
     if ($compareWith == $toCompare) $compareResult[] = $compare;
}
```

Comment: i did do the corrections you said but still get an empty array as a result

Comment: Becase you give limited information, edit your question and add `products` table structure and the result of array with which details you want